# Increment a random number with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to coding and I have the following problem:
I created a random number and I have it in a p tag which has a class, then I tried to increment this number by clicking on a button. This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

let films = JSON.parse(movies);

for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++){

    let movie = `
    <div class="container">
        <div class="poster">
            <img class="pic" src="${films[i].image}">
        </div>
        <div class="text-box">
            <div class="details">
                <h2>${films[i].title}</h2>
                <p>${films[i].releaseDate}</p>
                <p>Genre: ${films[i].genre}</p>
                <p>Director: ${films[i].director}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="like-box">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Like &#128077;" number="${i}"></input>
                <p class="counter"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    `;
    $("#main2").append(movie);
    $(".counter").text(Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1));
}

    $(".btn").click(function() {
        let el = parseInt($(".counter").text());
        $(".counter").text(el+1);
    })
```

});

The problem is, that if I click on the button instead of getting for example: 19 then after the click 20, what I get is 191919191920. So basically the button works, but not exactly how I want it to work. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Why is `movies` a string?

Comment: @Andreas it’s probably json

Comment: Yes, its the json file which contains the data Im displaying on the html.

Comment: @evolutionxbox In a `document.ready` handler?

Comment: @user13735786 where is ‘movies‘ defined?

Comment: [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/): _"**Get the combined text contents of each element in the set** of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements."_

Comment: Solution provided as an answer. You may need to re-modify your code to add row counter as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes you would need to do:**

Add new class to the container increaseing row count. This is mandatory to identify which movie you're on and increase the like value.

```
<div class='container row-" +i+ "'">
```

Then add onClick event to the like button to pass which row you're on. This is to identify which counter to increase the value.

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Like &#128077;" number="1" onclick="incrementLikes('row-" +i+ "')"></input>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".counter").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
});

function incrementLikes(rowId) {
  let mainRow = document.getElementsByClassName(rowId)[0];
  let counter = parseInt(mainRow.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0].innerHTML);
  mainRow.getElementsByClassName('counter')[0].innerHTML = counter + 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container row-1">
  <div class="poster">
    <img class="pic" src="">
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">
    <div class="details">
      <h2>Film Title 1</h2>
      <p>13/06/2020</p>
      <p>Genre: Action</p>
      <p>Director: John Doe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="like-box">
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Like &#128077;" number="1" onclick="incrementLikes('row-1')"></input>
      <p class="counter"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container row-2">
  <div class="poster">
    <img class="pic" src="">
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">
    <div class="details">
      <h2>Film Title 2</h2>
      <p>13/06/2020</p>
      <p>Genre: Action</p>
      <p>Director: John Doe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="like-box">
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Like &#128077;" number="1" onclick="incrementLikes('row-2')"></input>
      <p class="counter"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container row-3">
  <div class="poster">
    <img class="pic" src="">
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">
    <div class="details">
      <h2>Film Title 3</h2>
      <p>13/06/2020</p>
      <p>Genre: Action</p>
      <p>Director: John Doe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="like-box">
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Like &#128077;" number="1" onclick="incrementLikes('row-3')"></input>
      <p class="counter"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"However for a complete solution we would need sample of the json data you're passing"_ - Then why do you add an answer when you don't know if this will work?

Comment: I found the error and providing the complete solution. i will amend the post. :)

Comment: I tried this solution but I got an  error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".

Comment: @user13735786 hope you have done the suggestions i made to identify which row you're on.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++){
```

after this for loop is done, there will be `films.length` elements in dom with class `counter`. 
and what this `$(".counter").text()` will return is  concatenation of all text in elements with classes `counter`. That's why you got `191919191920`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your selector `".counter"`

`$(".counter").text` returns the combined string value of all elements that have the class `".counter"`

I have modified your code using selectors specific to the clicked button

```
let films = JSON.parse(movies);

for (let i = 0; i < films.length; i++){
    let buttonId = "button" + i;
    let movie = `
    <div class="container">
        <div class="poster">
            <img class="pic" src="${films[i].image}">
        </div>
        <div class="text-box">
            <div class="details">
                <h2>${films[i].title}</h2>
                <p>${films[i].releaseDate}</p>
                <p>Genre: ${films[i].genre}</p>
                <p>Director: ${films[i].director}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="like-box">
                <input id="${buttonId}" type="button" class="btn" value="Like &#128077;" number="${i}"></input>
                <p class="counter"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    `;
    $("#main2").append(movie);
    $("#${buttonId}.btn").next().text(Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1));
}

    $("#${buttonId}.btn").click(function() {
        let el = parseInt($("#${buttonId}.btn").next().text());
        $("#${buttonId}.btn").next().text(el+1);
    })
```

Comment: @user13735786 I have updated your code in my answer. pls check it

Comment: @user13735786 let me know if you need more explanation about my changes